# Pull a variable out of multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 functions where I manipulate a dataframe to create a new version of it. I need to pull out the last version of the adjusted dataframe out of each function to use them elsewhere. Keep in mind that df_1 is not the returned dataframe but rather an intermediate variable. So running the functions wouldn't return the variable I need.

For example I have the functions below and need to merge df1 from function_1, df1 from function_2, and df1 from function_3. However, when I run a function and set it says df1 is not defined. I could set it to global but is there another way? Thank you.

```
def funciton_1():
    df1=df1.apply()
    df1.dropna... 
    df_name=pd.merge(df1, df_name, how='outer')
    #other manipulations df_name
return df_name
def funciton_2():
    df1=df1[[column names]]
    df1.replace('([regex]])','',regex=True,inplace=True)
return df_name
def funciton_3():
    df1=df1[[column names]]
    df1.replace('([regex]])','',regex=True,inplace=True)
    df1=df1.apply()
    df1.dropna...`enter code here`return df_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is that if you work with methods local scope and you don't use any global scope. Pass the dataframe you want to modify as a parameter and return the modified version. That way your code becomes more modular, easy to test and to follow. That way you can write:

```
df1 = function_1(df)
df2 = function_2(df1)
df3 = function_3(df2)

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

Comment: Sorry, should've specified earlier. I don't need the return of the function, because there are other dataframes that are manipulated and merged. The return of the function wouldn't satisfy it.

Comment: Anyway, working with global state and modifying it in functions is not a good practice. It would be much better if you structure your code so you don't need to do that, for readability and maintainability reasons.